# Can I merge Minecraft accounts?

Tags: android, minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

We have a Nintendo Switch Minecraft account and now I've bought the app for my android phone.  Is there any way I can use the switch account details on my phone? (So it's the same worlds we're playing in?)
Thanks x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid that you won’t be able to merge the two accounts. Minecraft on a phone can only link with Microsoft (XBox) accounts, unfortunately not with Nintendo Switch ones.

Hope this info helps you!